# why questions with "too broad" tag are ignored or downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, voting

I have been using SO from 1 year. In that period, I have seen many questions with "too broad" tag. Such questions are always found with -5 to -10 down votes and sometimes even worse. When I went through such questions I have seen many people who ask such questions are either new users or they are new to question area ex. Java, performance, optimization etc.

Some experts (because of their high score) and their **"great"** knowledge mark that question as "too broad" and down vote it. Though question is quite simple or sometimes that user needs some pointers to solution maybe an area or place where he can search for answer.

Because of such too broad tags other people down vote that question and that question will be ignored. This behavior highly demotivates the user. If experts want more info then,

1. Either they should ask for more info
2. Another better solution could be create a new tag "need more info" or similar.

Down voting on such questions should be limited i.e. requires some reputation (>10000 or less where no. of users will be less) or users who has marked it as "need more info" or "too broad".

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you're confusing causality here. Often, these questions are downvoted because they are bad, *then* closed. They aren't downvoted because of the close reason, they're downvoted because of the poor quality of the question.

Answer (score 18):

Whenever I've closed and/or downvoted on a too broad question, they've generally taken on the form:

> I'm new to [language].  I want to write a website that can support tens of thousands of users.  How do I do that?

That's ***hopelessly*** unanswerable here.  There is literally nothing that anyone could ask to narrow it down to a question that:

- is simple enough to answer, and
- be of any use to anyone else using the site.

If a user doesn't want to [read the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and see what we would accept as valid questions, then they *shouldn't* be here.  Full stop.